# Don't get number if precede by month python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, jupyter

I'm pulling some data out of the web utilizing python in the Jupyter notebook. I have pulled down the data, parsed, and created the data frame. I have extracted a number out of a string that I have in a variable in the data frame. I utilizing this regex to do it:

```
number = []
for note in df["person_notes"]:
    match = re.search(r'\d+', note)
    if match:
        number.append(note[match.start(): match.end()])
    else:
        number.append("")

df["number"] = number
```

Some strings are missing the number I'm looking for. For those cases, I will like to `number.append("")`. Those strings have instead a full date like so... "September 20, 2016" and my `re.search()` is pulling the number 20 out of that full date. If the string has a data like so, I want to ignore the 20 and instead I want to `number.append("")`.

How can I modify the `re.search()` to ignore the number if the number is preceded by a month?

Comment: What are examples of strings where you *do* want to get the number of?

Comment: So, you only have 1  number per a note? Note you can acess the match with `match.group()` (no need using `note[match.start(): match.end()]`).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew for some reason `age.append(note[match.group()])` returns an error `TypeError: string indices must be integesrs`

Comment: `age.append(match.group())`

Comment: You may use `r'((?:Jan|Febr)(?:uary)?|Ma(?:y|r(?:ch)?)|A(?:ug(?:ust)?|pr(?:il)?)|Ju(?:ne?|ly?)|Oct(?:ober)?|(?:Sept|Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?)? *(\d+)'` regex and only append the value to `numbers` if Group 1 did not match - see http://ideone.com/YPKS5p

Comment: Yes, `age.append(match.group())` works as you expected. Thank you!! Learning regular expressions for cleaning data.

Comment: What about the latest comment? I do not know if you need shortened month names, but they can all be written in an easier way like `(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your previous code did work... `r'((?:Jan|Febr)(?:uary)?|Ma(?:y|r(?:ch)?)|A(?:ug(?:ust)?|pr(‌​?:il)?)|Ju(?:ne?|ly?‌​)|Oct(?:ober)?|(?:Se‌​pt|Nov|Dec)(?:ember)‌​?)? *(\d+)'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you can post your solution so I can up vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest useing the old JS regex trick: enclose the pattern you wouldenclose with a negative lookbehind with an *optional capturing group*, and if it is a success, discard the match (here, append a `""`). Else, grab the other capturing group contents (here, the digits).

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/YPKS5p):

```
import re
number = []
p = re.compile(r'((?:Jan|Febr)(?:uary)?|Ma(?:y|r(?:ch)?)|A(?:ug(?:ust)?|pr(?:il)?)|Ju(?:ne?|ly?)|Oct(?:ober)?|(?:Sept|Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?)? *(\d+)')
match = p.search('September 20, 2016')
if match and not match.group(1):         # Did the string match and did Group 1 fail?
    number.append(match.group(2))        # Yes, then add digits
else:
    number.append("")                    # Else, add an empty value
print(number)
```

If you do not care about the shortened month names and keep it readable, you may use a simpler regex:

```
p = re.compile(r'(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September‌​|October|November|De‌​cember)? *(\d+)')
```

The regex matches:

- `((?:Jan|Febr)(?:uary)?|Ma(?:y|r(?:ch)?)|A(?:ug(?:ust)?|pr(?:il)?)|Ju(?:ne?|ly?)|Oct(?:ober)?|(?:Sept|Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?)?` - months (full or short names)
- `*` - zero or more spaces
- `(\d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits.